# Wrapping one of many methods on a type struct?

Tags: go

A library I use has a type with multiple methods:

```
type Foo struct {
}

func (f *Foo) method1() int { ... }
func (f *Foo) method2() int { ... }
func (f *Foo) method3() int { ... }
// ... and so on
```

I'd really like to apply some specific behavior anytime I call `method1` on this type:

```
func (f *Foo) method1Wrapper() int {
    incrementCounter()
    return f.method1()
}
```

But this adds a *new* method I'd have to call *instead* of just directly calling `method1()` itself.

Alternatively, I imagine I could create my own type:

```
type Foo2 struct {
    Foo
}

func (f *Foo2) method1() int {
    incrementCounter()
    return f.Foo.method1()
}
```

But then I'd have to create a bunch of boilerplate code to proxy all the calls to `method2`, `method3`, etc down to the `Foo` implementation, *and* I'd have to change all my usages of `Foo` to `Foo2`.

Is it possible to directly patch or wrap `Foo.method1()` itself *without* creating a subclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to proxy the method calls to delegate them, this is exactly what [embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) is for.

```
type Foo struct {
}

func (f *Foo) method1() int { return 1 }
func (f *Foo) method2() int { return 2 }
func (f *Foo) method3() int { return 3 }

type Foo2 struct {
    *Foo
}

func (f Foo2) method1() int {
    fmt.Println("WRAPPED")
    return f.Foo.method1()
}
```

`Foo2` has the same method set as `Foo`, but `method1` is "intercepted" by `Foo2`, which explicitly calls `Foo.method1` internally.

https://play.golang.org/p/q8tea5ZuHl4